# Azure Service Bus: AMQP object is closing. Operation 'attach' cannot be performed

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm using Azure Service Bus Topics with the AMQP protocol in the West Europe datacenter. 
This is a schematic way of how the solution implented works:

```
private Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SubscriptionClient CreateClient() {
    string serviceBusConnectionString;
    strin serviceBusTopicName;
    string subscriptionName;

    var subscriptionClient = new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SubscriptionClient(serviceBusConnectionString, serviceBusTopicName, subscriptionName) {
                PrefetchCount = 0
            };
    return subscriptionClient;
}

public async Task<ISubscriptionClient> CreateSubscriptionClientAsync() {
    //Some logic on the subscriptionClient, caching, creating a new one if it doesn't exists, etc.
    return CreateClient()
}

private async Task CallbackAsync(Message msg, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    //Do stuff with the Message
    //when you're done Completethe message
}

public async Task<string> OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    subscriptionClient = await CreateSubscriptionClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandlerAsync) {
            AutoComplete = false,
            MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromHours(8)
    };
    subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(CallbackAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
    return string.Empty;
}
```

But last night I had couple of thousand exception like this one:

```
Exception: "System.InvalidOperationException: The AMQP object g2b-sessionXXXXXXXX is closing. Operation 'attach' cannot be performed.
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.<OnReceiveAsync>d__86.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.<>c__DisplayClass64_0.<<ReceiveAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

I'm using the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus v3.1.0.0, 
On line I didn't find anything useful about this "Operation 'attach' cannot be performed".

On the message bus [exception list page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) I didn't find any information about this specific problem. And in the [status history site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/) there is no reference about any outage involving Service Bus.

Did anyone experience this problem before?
What is causing the exception?
Do I need to implement any retry logic? How?
Any help is apreciated, thanks.